# In the entity framework, how would you do an "IN" query on a joined table?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm a SQL junkie, and the syntax of the EF is not intuitive to me.

I have a Restaurant table and a Food table. I want the restaurants and foods where the foods have a type contained in the string list Categories. Here is some SQL that roughly represents what I want.

```
SELECT r.*, f.*
FROM Restaurant R
  JOIN food f on f.RestaurantID = r.RestaurantID
WHERE f.Type IN ("Awesome", "Good", "Burrito")
```

Here's the code I want to turn into that SQL.

```
List<string> types = new List<string>() { "Awesome", "Good", "Burrito"};
var dbrestaurants = from d in db.Restaurants
                    .Include("Food")
                    //where Food.Categories.Contains(types)//what to put here?
                    select d;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var restaurants = db.Restaurants.Where(r => types.Contains(r.Food.Type));
```

Comment: (similar to my other comment) - "Category" is a property of an individual Food item, not the Food collection (instead of Type), so using something like r.Food.Type won't work AFAIK.

Comment: I only see the tables Restaurant and Food in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
where Food.Categories.Any(c => types.Contains(c.Name))
```

Comment: So, I put that in my code, and I get: Error 1 Delegate 'System.Func<MyProj.Models.Restaurant,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: Probably, that is because I do not know all the classes and members that you have. I must have gotten something wrong. Try this: where types.Contains(Food.Type)

Comment: I guess the issue I'm running up against is that "Type" is not available as a property on the Food collection. It's only available on the individual Food items within the collection.

Comment: Well, you can see how this is done. I guess you can adapt this technique to your own object model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dbRestaurants = 
from r in db.Restaurants
join f in db.Foods on r.RestaurantId equals f.RestaurantId
where types.Any(foodType => foodType == f.Type)
select r;
```